# Resize Array, if it is too small for user input without string.h

Tags: c

How can I expand the array, once it is too small for the user input? For example, if char array[25] can only have 25 elements, but my sentence is 100 character long.
Is there way to do it without string.h library?
I am very new to this language and have problems with understanding dynamic allocation. And I cant find the solution in internet without using string.h

Comment: You can't resize an array, but you can define it to be at least as long as you will need. Note that your sentence, a string, can only be 24 elements long here.

Comment: Post your code and we can review it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you'll need to manage your own memory allocation *(in C++, std::vector makes this a lot easier)*. This is a very basic example of an expanding array of integers...

```cpp
/* how many array elements are we using? */
int len = 0;

/* maximum capacity for the array - may change if we exceed the capacity */
int capacity = 128;

/* dynamic arrays are a pointer, with some memory allocation */
int* array = (int*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(int));

/* an example loop */
for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {

  /* if we are at capacity */
  if(len == capacity) {

    /* reallocate the array to be twice the size */
    capacity = capacity * 2;
    array = (char*)realloc(array, capacity * sizeof(int));
  }

  /* add new item into array */
  array[len++] = i;
}

/* make sure we free the memory eventually to avoid a memory leak... */
if(array) free(array);
```

Comment: thank you. I think, now I understand it better.